# Do not wipe out (user entered) values of reactive variables when changing input values

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to collect individual information (name and age) as user input with the attached demo code. The initial number of individuals is 1, and when the user increases/decreases the value of the number of individuals, it will reactively add/reduce corresponding rows to collect individual information. My question is how to avoid wiping out the current input information when increasing/decreasing the number of individuals. For example, **screenshot 1** shows the information of individual 1 entered by the user (me). When I changed the values of the number of individuals to 2, the information I entered before was wiped out (**screenshot 2**), and I had to re-enter the information for individual 1. What I expect will be like **screenshot 3** (information for individual 1 is not wiped out) when I increase the number of individuals to 2. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

**Update on 05/15/2022**

The update answer using `isolate` is what I am looking for. Thanks again for the help from @jpdugo17.

**Example code**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      h4("Individual Information"),
      fluidRow(column(4,numericInput("ninds",
                                     label = "Number of individuals",
                                     value = 1, min = 1, step = 0.5, width = "300px"))),
      br(),
      fluidRow(column(2,align = "center",strong("Individual #")),
               column(5,align = "center",strong("Individual Name")),
               column(5,align = "center",strong("Age"))),
      fluidRow(
        column(2,wellPanel(uiOutput("indNum"))),
        column(5,wellPanel(uiOutput("Name"))),
        column(5,wellPanel(uiOutput("Age"))))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # create reactive variable paste0("individualNum", i) for further using
  output$indNum <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$ninds)
    req(num)
    lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      numericInput(paste0("individualNum", i), value = i, label = "", max = i, min = i)
    })
  })
  # create reactive variable paste0("name", i) for further using 
  output$Name <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$ninds)
    req(num)
    lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      textInput(paste0("name", i), label = "")
    })
  })
  # create reactie variable paste0("age", i) for further using 
  output$Age <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$ninds)
    req(num)
    lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      numericInput(paste0("age", i), label = "", value = 0)
    })
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**screenshot-1**
[image: screenshot-1]
**screenshot-2**
[image: screenshot-2]
**screenshot-3**
[image: screenshot-3]

Comment: On average , how many individuals will the app have at any given time?

Comment: In my case, I would say usually less than 15 individuals. @jpdugo17

Comment: The simplest case would be to initialize the app with the inputs for 15 individuals but show or hide them on user request. The other alternative is to use insertUI function. What kind of solution do you prefer?

Comment: Thanks. @jpdugo17. The first option is not good for my case. In terms of insertUI, I just checked it and it seems to me it will add an independent UI object. In my app, I will need the reactive variables created in the server (e.g., numericInput(paste0("age", i), label = "", value = 0)) for downstream using. Would this insertUI work? Also, I noticed some posts combined insertUI with modules, would this also work for my case? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

We can use `isolate` with the current value of the input and pass it as the value argument in the `numericInput` or `textInput`. This will work because any input that doesn't exist yet will yield a `NULL`.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  # create reactive variable paste0("individualNum", i) for further using

  num <- reactive({
    req(input$ninds)
    input$ninds
  })

  output$indNum <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:num(), function(i) {
      numericInput(paste0("individualNum", i), value = i, label = "", max = i, min = i)
    })
  })
  # create reactive variable paste0("name", i) for further using
  output$Name <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:num(), function(i) {
      textInput(paste0("name", i), label = "", value = isolate(input[[paste0("name", i)]]))
    })
  })
  # create reactie variable paste0("age", i) for further using
  output$Age <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:num(), function(i) {
      numericInput(paste0("age", i), label = "", value = isolate(input[[paste0("age", i)]]))
    })
  })
}
```

Original answer using `insertUI`:

We can implement a logic like this: Create a counter to store the current input number, make two buttons, one to add and the other to remove the inputs. We'll have to wrap each input with a div with a unique id (because input functions usually add multiple elements).

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      h4("Individual Information"),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          4, fluidRow(
            column(6, numericInput("ninds",
              label = "Number of individuals",
              value = 1, min = 1, step = 0.5, width = "300px"
            )), column(3, actionButton("add_ui", "Add Individual", style = "background-color: green;")),
            column(3, actionButton("remove_ui", "Remove Individual", style = "background-color: red;"))
          )
        )
      ),
      br(),
      fluidRow(
        column(2, align = "center", strong("Individual #")),
        column(5, align = "center", strong("Individual Name")),
        column(5, align = "center", strong("Age"))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(2, wellPanel(id = "IndNumber")),
        column(5, wellPanel(id = "Name")),
        column(5, wellPanel(id = "Age"))
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # track the number of inputs
  ui_counter <- reactiveVal(1)

  observeEvent(input$add_ui, {
    div_nms <- map_chr(c("individualNum", "name", "age"), ~ paste0("div", .x, ui_counter()))

    # individual number
    insertUI(
      selector = "#IndNumber",
      ui = div(
        id = div_nms[[1]],
        numericInput(paste0("individualNum", ui_counter()),
          label = "",
          value = ui_counter(),
          min   = ui_counter(),
          max   = ui_counter()
        )
      )
    )

    # name input
    insertUI(
      selector = "#Name",
      ui = div(id = div_nms[[2]], textInput(paste0("name", ui_counter()),
        label = ""
      ))
    )

    # age input
    insertUI(
      selector = "#Age",
      ui = div(id = div_nms[[3]], numericInput(paste0("age", ui_counter()),
        label = "",
        value = 0
      ))
    )


    ui_counter(ui_counter() + 1)
  })

  # observer to remove the divs containing the inputs
  observeEvent(input$remove_ui, {
    if (ui_counter() > 1) {
      walk(c("individualNum", "name", "age"), ~ removeUI(paste0("#div", .x, ui_counter() - 1)))
      ui_counter(ui_counter() - 1)
    }
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Great! @jpdugo17. The only question I have is the current "numericInput" does not reactive with "actionButton" or vice versa. One way I can see is to replace "numericInput" with "textOutput" which will depend on "actionButton", but this will a one-direction dependence (actionButton influences textOutput). I just want to check if there are better solutions before I accept your answer. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @OceanSky_U Please, see my edit, now you can select the numeber of individuals from the numericInput like before.

Comment: Wonderful! Seems like 'isolate' is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks! @jpdugo17